# comex gold futures contracts with two brokers

Tags: futures

Can I close a gold futures contract for sale with one broker, with a purchase contract with another broker?

Comment: Yes. What makes you think you can't?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Whether it is profitable or not is different and depends on the quotes as well as brokerage charges.